# How can I switch between front and back camera in Unity when most mobile phones have multiple back cameras?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, switch-statement, device

I am trying to switch device front and back camera in unity.

I tried following code, but currently most of the mobile phone have more than one back cameras.
When I press the switch button, it will transfer to another one of the back camera, not the front camera.
Can anyone help

```
    WebCamTexture webCamTexture;
    WebCamDevice[] devices;
    
    void Start() 
    {
        devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        webCamTexture.deviceName = devices[0].name;
        webCamTexture.Play();
    }
    
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if( GUI.Button( new Rect(0,0,100,100), "switch" ))
        {
        webCamTexture.Stop();
        webCamTexture.deviceName = (webCamTexture.deviceName == devices[0].name) ? devices[1].name : devices[0].name;
        webCamTexture.Play();
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: well that code only ever uses the first answer of the array - what else is in the array

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebCamDevice.isFrontFacing`

```cs
WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
foreach(var device in devices)
{
    if (device.isFrontFacing) {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```